# Exporting a List into Excel

Tags: r, excel

I'm currently struggling with creating a nice output file for performed regressions.

I stored all my performed regressions (25) with the lm function in a list. It is very inconvenient to analyze the output in R (at least i don't know how to do it efficiently). For that reason I d like to export all my results in an Excel Sheet.

The list called "myregressions" has 25 entries of the 25 regressions which are named after the performed year : myregression$year_1988 - myregression$year_2011 with all the information on coefficients, residuals, effects rank etc.

Is there an easy way to accomplish that? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You will have to do a lot of playing around to accommodate all this into an excel sheet. If you'd like to store this for posterity, I would suggest you use `save`.

Comment: Can't you just summary(lm-object) to display all that information? And what difficulties are you facing trying to analyze the output. I can't really think of any situation where Excel is more convenient than R for anything (but I'm biased).

Comment: thank you i used the simple write.csv which was very convenient. As i am very new to R i'm unfortunately struggling with the simplest tasks. I hope there will be a steep learningcurve though :)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the list into a data frame, and then do something like this:

```
dataFrameToCSV = function(dataFrame, path)
{
  write.table(dataFrame, path, sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
}
```